# Using AWK to filter out column with numerical ranges

Tags: bash, numbers, awk, range

I'm relatively new to BASH and I'm trying to use awk to filter out column 1 data based on the 4th column of a text file. If the 4th column of data matches the range of x, then it'll output column 1 data. "x" is suppose to be a range of numbers 1-10 (1,2,3..10).

```
awk -F: '{ if($4=="x") print $1}' filename.txt

filename.txt 
sample1 0 0 4
sample2 0 0 10
sample3 0 0 15
sample4 0 0 20
```

Actual use:

```
awk -F: '{ if($4=="1-10") print $1}' sample.txt
output = sample1, sample2, sample3, sample4
```

It should be: `sample1 sample2` only.

Is there is an error in the syntax that I'm not seeing or I could be possibly using this syntax completely wrong?

Answer (score 75):

```
awk '{ if ($4 >= 1 && $4 <= 10) print $1 }' sample.txt
```

Comment: You can use expressions as patterns and do away with the `if`, like so:`awk '$4 <= 10 && $4 >= 1 { print $1 }' file.txt`

Comment: Also, `awk '1 <= $4 && $4 <= 10' sample.txt` works great for people like me that want to output whole lines based on value of one column.

Comment: @arekolek may I ask what should I do if my 1 and 10 are variables $one and $ten? I tried     awk '"'"$one"'" <= $4 && $4 <= "'"$ten"'"' sample.txt    , but the less than ten part did not work somehow

Comment: @Helene, I understand `one` is a bash variable, so I'd try `awk "$one <= \$4 && \$4 <= $ten"` so that bash substitutes only `$one` and `$ten` in the string passed to `awk`.

Comment: Use `-v` option to [pass variable into awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script): `awk -v a="$one" -v b="$ten" 'a <= $4 && $4 <= b'`

Answer (score 18):

```
awk '$4 ~ /^[1-9]$|^10$/{print $1}' sample.txt
```

output:

```
sample1
sample2
```

explanation:

- `^[1-9]$` --> $4 must be a single digit from 1 to 9
- `|`    (the pipe)  --> or
- `^10$`     -->   $4 must be the number 10

Answer (score 8):

```
awk -F ':' '$4 >= 1 && $4 <= 10{print $1}'
```

Comment: already suggested in comments. Read all the answers before answering something very similar, specially if the question is old.

Answer (score 4):

There may be a way to do it using only awk (nevermind, see my edit below), but I don't know of it. I'd combine it with grep:

```
egrep ' ([1-9]|10)$' sample.txt | awk '{print $1}'
```

I think you are matching the fourth column with the string "1-10" not the range. Also, `-F:` will change the delimiter to a colon rather than a space.

Edit:

```
awk '$4 ~ /^([1-9]|10)$/ {print $1}' sample.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want `awk` to look up values from a range then you can set that range in the `BEGIN` statement.

```
awk 'BEGIN{for (i=1;i<=10;i++) a[i]} ($4 in a){print $1}' sample.txt
```

#### Test:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat sample.txt 
sample1 0 0 4
sample2 0 0 10
sample3 0 0 15
sample4 0 0 20
[jaypal:~/Temp] awk 'BEGIN{for (i=1;i<=10;i++) a[i]} ($4 in a){print $1}' sample.txt 
sample1
sample2
```

Answer (score 1):

If Perl is an option, you can try this solution similar to Kambus's awk solution:

```
perl -lane 'print $F[0] if $F[3] >= 1 && $F[3] <= 10' sample.txt
```

These command-line options are used:

- `-n` loop around every line of the input file, do not automatically print every line
- `-l` removes newlines before processing, and adds them back in afterwards
- `-a` autosplit mode – split input lines into the @F array.
- `-e` execute the perl code

`@F` is the array of words in each line, indexed starting with 0